# Authenticate users with remote server in Yii framework

Tags: authentication, yii

I am using yii framework for an application and I need a set of users to be authenticated with a remote server.

I have few user roles in my application. for ex:

- Super Administrator
- Brand Administrator
- Customer 
  etc...

All the customer records are in a remote MySQL database. I have to authenticate the customers through my yii application. My yii application will be hosted in a different server.

Please assume that I can place a php script in the remote server to response my post requests.

Do I need to write my own UserIdentity class to do this?

Please help me on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to put any script in your remote server, all you need is

```
1. Access the remote Db, and Yii allows the use of [multiple-databases][1].
2. Adjust the model(s) you are using for Authentication/Authorization (usually the User model) to load it's data from the remote database
```

**For the First task:**

```php
// protected/main/config.php

return array(
...
'components' => array(
    'db' => array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=dbserver1;dbname=my1db',
        ...
    ),
    'remotedb' => array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=adserver2;dbname=advertisingDB',
        'username'         => 'username',
        'password'         => '***********',
        ...
        'class'            => 'CDbConnection'          // DO NOT FORGET THIS!
    ),
```

**For the second task:**

For the model(s) you are using to **Authenticate** & **Authorize**, you will need to override the `getDbConnection()` function to load the needed data from the remote server. 
Check the [Wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/) for **How**.

And, Yes. You will need to write your own `UserIdentity` class, actually its a usual task even if you havn't use a remote Db since it's default logic is only an example and not for real production sites.

GoodLuck!

Comment: Hi Nimir, Thank you for the help. I have created another User Model for Remote user authentication as your advise. Now everything works great!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to rewrite the component UserIdentity and create their own rules authentication.